# Install paradox php extension

Tags: php, paradox

I have tried to install the paradox extension for PHP
http://php.net/manual/en/paradox.installation.php

But I get the following error message

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-45-59:/opt/install/paradox-1.4.3$ sudo pecl install paradox
downloading paradox-1.4.3.tgz ...
Starting to download paradox-1.4.3.tgz (20,662 bytes)
........done: 20,662 bytes
4 source files, building
running: phpize
Cannot find config.m4.
Make sure that you run '/usr/bin/phpize' in the top level source directory of the module

If the command failed with 'phpize: not found' then you need to install php5-dev packageYou can do it by running 'apt-get install php5-dev' as a root userERROR: `phpize' failed
ubuntu@ip-172-31-45-59:/opt/install/paradox-1.4.3$
```

I have also tried to compile it manually
http://pastebin.com/j9y3Ndb9

Comment: The first comment on the installation page implies that a patch is required when installing this on newer PHP versions than 5.5 - does that apply?

Comment: Hi, how do I apply this patch? I don't understand the documentation.

Comment: Ok I solved it by deleting the rules where "-" was in front and adding the rules with "+" in front of them. Tnx.